# CoreData Performance and Field Autocomplete

Tags: iphone, core-data, autocomplete

I have this remote database of artists. About 6,000 entries for now. I want my app to:

1. download a JSON-formatted index of the artist names (~95kb)
2. import that data to CoreData
3. provide suggestions/auto-complete when the user adds a new artist

I've done this before, but not on such a big scale. **Will it become problematic when the database reaches 20 or 30 thousand entries?** I'm not worried about the JSON filesize but mostly about CoreData's ability to quickly fetch data using an NSPredicate such as `artist_name LIKE textField.text` every time the textField changes value.

Comment: CoreData's performance will rely on the storage (SQLite, XML,...) I did use SQLite on the iPhone for several thousands entries for this kind of requests, and it was always very smooth. I did use the SQLite library directly though (not through CoreData), but CoreData is said to be very efficient, so I think it should be OK.

Comment: Me use SQLite For more Then 2500 entry its working fine and my friend work on SQLite more then 10000 entry and give search in less then one second , its work fine in this case Me never use coredata so not know the profomance of it , hope you give reply after use both which one is better so i use it in my application next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the very least, make sure you mark artist_name as indexed... that should help.

I'd also investigate other predicates and see if there's not a substring specific one that might perform better than LIKE.

You'll also want to look into pre-loading a database that holds that much data, and update it in the background... a 300k JSON file will take a LONG time to download if the network is at all poor.

Comment: Yea BEGINSWITH actually makes more sense. Even though the autocomplete feature is a nicety, it's indeed a good idea to preload the app with some stock database. Thanks for the tips!